# Chrome extension icons fritzing out

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extensions, icons

I'm having trouble diagnosing this in part because I don't know what to look for on Google. About a week ago my Adblock and download icons on Chrome went all "noisy":

[image: Screenshot 1] [image]

These noisy bits blur around in different patterns every time I open a new page. This persists across restarting the app and the computer.

Anyone know what the deal is? And/or how to go about fixing it?

Comment: Try first clearing the cache (`Ctrl+Shift+Delete`), then try updating your extensions (`chrome://extensions`->Developer Mode->Update Extensions Now)

Comment: Thanks @Synetech— good advice. What I outline below fixed the problem for me.

Answer (score 0):

Got it!

1. Uninstall the extension (Adblock, in this case)
2. RESTART (Missed this one the first time, and the problem came back)
3. Reinstall the app.

Success.